# Creating a partial index on JSONB field existence in Postgres gives me PG::ProgramLimitExceeded. But why?

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

The SQL query that I would like to optimize by adding the partial index is the following:

```
SELECT * FROM emails WHERE state ? 'failure'
```

I am trying to create a partial index on the existence of a JSONB field (here: `state -> failure`) in a Postgres database table. The SQL statement looks like this:

```
CREATE INDEX "partial_index_failure_on_emails" ON "emails" ("state") WHERE (state ? 'failure')
```

Each time I try to execute the SQL statement to add this index, the database fails with the following error:

```
PG::ProgramLimitExceeded: ERROR:  index row requires 13080 bytes, maximum size is 8191
```

I have no idea what might cause this error as the resulting index should be a boolean, which definitely does not require more than 8191 bytes - not even close.

What am I missing?

I also tried to use a similar index definition, but that gives the same error:

```
CREATE INDEX "partial_index_failure_on_emails" ON "emails" ("state") WHERE (state -> 'failure') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Can we see the table definition?

Comment: "*as the resulting index should be a boolean"*  no it's not. You are putting the **complete** JSON value into the index, not just a boolean value. What kind of query do you want that index to support?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I just updated my question to include the query that I would like the partial index to support